# Adding a layer on top of eSearch widget using web appbuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I added one layer on top of eSearch widget and its working in fine when we launch in WAB. I saved and  downloaded the code of updated eSearch widget. I found the same code as before adding layer to it and also I have seen in server/apps/2/widgets/eSearch/config.json, but 'config.json' file showing the same code with some other services layers.

Where I can find the updated code after adding layers ?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer this will help.

In WAB once you configure a widget using the widgets settings page and then save, a new json file is added in a different location. Look in this path: [install dir]\server\apps\2\configs\eSearch\config_Enhanced Search.json